# Two divs to be placed in a single bootstrap row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following `html` code, I am not able to place the `div`s in a single row. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hey there!</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class=".col-md-4">Hello</div>
        <div class=".col-md-8"><h1>How are you?</h1></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove the . from before the class name.

Comment: @ChipDean ohh...thanks a lot...I went blind-eyed here :)..thanks again!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Hello</div>
    <div class="col-md-8"><h1>How are you?</h1>
</div>
```

The "."  is used for a selector, not when writing the class name